# Laravel Password Confirmation Failing Validation

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-validation

I'm using Vue.js in Laravel and I'm trying to validate a confirmation password. The passwords are the same, but I'm getting an error that they don't match.

```php
<div class="control-group">
    <input type="password" v-validate="'required'" name="password" id="password"
           placeholder="Create Password" class="form-control"
           data-vv-as="Create Password"
           v-model="user.password">
    <span class="red" v-show="errors.has('password')">{{ errors.first('password') }}</span>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <input type="password" v-validate="'required|confirmed:password'" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password"
           placeholder="Re-enter Password" class="form-control"
           data-vv-as="Re-enter Password"
           v-model="user.confirm_password">
    <span class="red" v-show="errors.has('confirm_password')">{{ errors.first('confirm_password') }}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From Laravel documentation

> **confirmed**
>
> *The field under validation must have a matching field of foo_confirmation. For example, if the field under validation is
>   password, a matching password_confirmation field must be present in
>   the input.*

The validation should be `required|confirmed` for `password` field and `required` for `password_confirmation` field. Otherwise the validation will try to find `password_confirmation_confirmation` field to confirm the value.

Please note the rename of the second field from `confirm_password` to `password_confirmation`.